# How do I sort the output of "ls" by last modified - including the date?

Tags: command-line, permissions, ls, manpage

So the output would be either:

Most recent at the top OR most recent at the bottom - **giving the times when the contents of the working directory were modified**?

Apparently, `ls -t` is supposed to give most recent at the top, which it does...

But I have no date when any of the file/folders were modified; which is rather annoying.

Is it possible to produce an output which lists the files in modified order, and also gives the time at which they were modified? I can't seem to find the option in `man`...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check the `-l` option of `ls`:

```
ls -lt
```

Neat way using `stat`:

```
stat -c '%y - %n' * | sort -t'-' -k1,1
```

Reverse:

```
stat -c '%y - %n' * | sort -r -t'-' -k1,1
```

- `%y` will give the modification time in human readable form, `%n` will give file name
- `sort` will sort the values according to only the modiication time